# Execute FFmpeg commands in android

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

I have all the ffmpeg´s files compiled in my android project, but I don´t know how to call ffmpeg commands. How can I get the "executable" file of the compiled library? What is it exactly?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
 try {
      Process ffmpegProcess = new ProcessBuilder(ffmpegCommand).redirectErrorStream(true).start();

      String line;
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ffmpegProcess.getInputStream()));
      Log.d(null, "*******Starting FFMPEG");

      while((line = reader.readLine())!=null){

          Log.d(null, "***"+line+"***"); 
      }
      Log.d(null,"****ending FFMPEG****");

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Comment: String ffmpegCommand="ffmpeg -i "+path.getAbsolutePath()+"/test/1.mp4 -f avi -acodec mp3 "+path.getAbsolutePath()+"/Songss.avi";    
i m passing ffmpegcommand in your example giving error  IOException
 **Working directory null IOEXception Executing below code.**

Comment: Okay I've just answered it in your question opened

Comment: in windows os 32 bit the ffmpeg libarary is not buliding ..please help me how to do that..

Comment: I am also getting working directory null exception.How to resolve it?